# Runtime error in java with apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
```

from the line 56:

```
public static Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

I just had to re-link my library, but all i did was move all the files and reset the build path to where i moved the files to, and removed the old one.

Comment: I had same problem, which turned out as old library of XMLBeans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
```

This statement says that you have mismatch(incompatible) of jars.  Make sure you have supported version of jars.

Comment: i grabbed everything new and relinked all the libraries and i get the same error. What do i do now?

Comment: Check again - you probably have two copies of the xmlbeans jar on your classpath, one of which is too old

Comment: @Thinksteep ha yes! i was using the version of xmlbeans that came with the apache poi which was version 2.3.0. downloaded and installed 2.5.0 and it works perfectly. thanks for the help! i didnt realize the version that came with it wasn't the most up to date.