# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I am trying to write a program which write the data in Excel. But i keep getting an error which is shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setSaveAggressiveNamespaces()Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
    at wriExcel.main(wriExcel.java:19)
```

On finding the solutions, I could only find that I should use `XMLBeans 2.0` or higher.
But, I am using `xmlbeans 2.3.0`.
Is there any other reason for this error.

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212652/runtime-error-in-java-with-apache-poi Check you classpath. There might be a conflicting older XMLBeans version somewhere, either bundled with some other library, or provided by whatever framework/appserver you are using.

Comment: @prashantk87 if your problem is solved by my answer then you can select my answer

Comment: thanks @KarlP, but there are no other conflicting XMLBeans version.

Comment: I can only point to the previous question. Download XMLBeans and place it early in the classpath.

Comment: Placing XMLBeans earlier in classpath worked. thanks KarlP

Answer (score 10):

Use `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` which resolves my problem...!

Comment: Previously I was using xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar. Now after changing to this version. It got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be because required needed for the project is not there so you have to download jar and then add that jar to your classpath
 [here is the link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlbeansxmlpublic240jar.htm)

find out which jar you need

Comment: try to download latest version of the jar

Answer (score 0):

Use the xmlbeans jar file shipped with PIO libraries, and avoid to download from any other source as there will be jar file conflicts.

You can find the xmlbeans under "ooxml-lib" shipped with PIO.