# ignore java extension libraries at class loading

Tags: java, apache-poi, classloader, xmlbeans

My problem is that for the program i currently write (ExcelProcessor) i use a library (Apache-POI) that needs the library XML-Beans that contains the class XMLOptions. The problem is that there is another library (XBean) that is outdated and is in the extension directory (JRE/ext) which provides the same class with the difference that there a needed method was named differently... (a corrected typo -.-).(Problem reference:[Runtime error in java with apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212652/runtime-error-in-java-with-apache-poi)) So since i musn't change the content of the extension directory what is the way to go in order to make the application to run again?

Dependencies:

- MyApp needs Apache POI
- Apache POI needs XMLBeans
- XMLBeans and XBean contain a different version of the org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions
- XBean is part of the java extension directory

Further information:

- the resulting application shall be a runnable jar -> no commandline available (for the common user)
- also the resulting application shall be an osgi(equinox) bundle that means it provides a service that makes the excelprocessor available to a gui. (how to implement that is not content of my question)

So are there any solutions regarding class loading that work from a normal runnable jar as well from being loaded by the osgi framework?

appreciating every answer... preferably nothing like "this is impossible" (if it is, are there workarounds?)

rapus95

Comment: Newer versions of XMLBeans should be backwards compatible with classes generated in old ones, so upgrading the version in JRE/ext ought to fix it. Can you try that / clarify why it won't work?

Comment: the problem is, that i don't have the permission (topic: IT-Service) to change the "setup" of the java vm/extensions since it's a business computer :/
Nevertheless i gonna check/ask whether someone could do that...
ty